# Roblox Studio - Workspace.(My roblox ign).Name:8: attempt to index nil with 'DisplayName'

Tags: list, lua, roblox

So I'm trying to choose a name out of a list and set the player's DisplayName to that..
This is a LocalScript in starterCharacterScripts.

````lua
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

print("Getting name of player ".. player.Name)
local Names = {<my names dont worry about em>}
local ChosenName = Names[math.random(1, #Names)]
print("Got name: " .. ChosenName)
local name = player.Name
game.Workspace.name.Humanoid.DisplayName = Names[math.random(1, #Names)]```
````

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't `ChosenName` used in the last line, instead of `Names[math.random(1, #Names)]`? This just chooses a random name for a second time, which may or may not match the name printed with `"Got name: "`.

But, to the matter at hand, what is the table referenced with `game.Workspace.name.Humanoid.DisplayName`? The error seems to indicate that there is no `DisplayName` field, so I suspect that there is no `Humanoid` field yet added to the table.

```
> Names = {'Trillian', 'Ford', 'Arthur', 'Zaphod', 'Marvin'}
> ChosenName = Names[math.random(1, #Names)]
```

If the table OP code is working with already has a `name` field, then:

```
> game.Workspace.name.Humanoid = { DisplayName = ChosenName }
```

will work. If the table does not yet have a `name` field, then:

```
> game.Workspace.name = { Humanoid = { DisplayName = ChosenName }}
```

Either way, you should now have:

```
> game.Workspace.name.Humanoid.DisplayName
Marvin
```

Unless the `game` table does not yet have a `Workspace` field. The general principle here is that `game.Workspace.name.Humanoid.DisplayName` is syntactic sugar for `game["Workspace"]["name"]["Humanoid"]["DisplayName"]`. If the `Workspace` field is a table, then an attempt to access the `name` field is made; if the `name` field is a table, then an attempt to access the `Humanoid` field is made. If the `Humanoid` field has not yet been created, `nil` is returned, and `["DisplayName"]` attempts to index `nil`, leading to the error.

Given a table like:

```
t = {}
```

You can create new fields *one level deep* with `t.something = something`, but you can't create nested table fields this way, e.g. `t.something.else = something_else`, because the first field `something` does not yet exist.